# I cannot read the puzzle file

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, wordsearch

[My coding that I have thus far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCEjk.png)

Im supposed to read from a file a word search puzzle my problem is it produces nothing but "i's" in the puzzle.  I don't know how to properly format a word puzzle to the file's specification. the format of a puzzle generally goes likes  this:
6  6
d e v o l g
r e d p h k
q c h z j c
p o a a f o
v a m m n l
q t f o x b
At the same time the file could give me a different size word search puzzle
    public static char[][] fill(){
        // Created 2 different scanner one for user input and one to read the file

```
    Scanner file1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    // created a count to add the keywords
    int count = 0;

    //System.out.print("Please enter a keyword to search for.");
    // Asking user to input a valid file name
    System.out.print("Please enter a valid puzzle file name\nYou will be asked for the same file name again later.");
    String wordFile = file1.nextLine();
    FileReader infile;
    boolean validFile = false;
    // Creating a while loop that will keep asking for a valid file name
    while(!validFile) {
        // Using a try and catch to obtain correct file
        try {
            infile = new FileReader(wordFile);
            file1 = new Scanner(infile);
            validFile = true;
        }
        //ask the user to put a valid file name if they are wrong
        catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Not a valid file name, please enter again!");
            wordFile = file1.nextLine();
        }
    }


    String numbers = file1.nextLine();
    String[] fileArray = numbers.trim().split(" ");

    int rows = Integer.parseInt(fileArray[0]);
    int columns = Integer.parseInt(fileArray[1]);

    char[][] fillThemLetters = new char [rows][columns];


    String letters = file1.nextLine().trim().replace(" ", "");

    char [] condensed =  letters.toCharArray(); 

    for (int i = 0; i < condensed.length; i++) {

        for(int row = 0; row < rows; row++){


            for(int column = 0; column < columns; column++)
            {
                char index = condensed[i];
                fillThemLetters[row][column] = index;

            }
        }

    }   
    return fillThemLetters;
}
```

Comment: what number would you like `red` to be?  BTW, post your code here as text, so we can copy-and-paste it into our favourite IDE

Comment: Red is one of the words that I was supposed to search for within the puzzle that I can't read

Comment: Well I guess the format of the file is not as you expect it.  Print out `numbers`

Comment: It print out the 6 6 which is the first two numbers that determine row and column of the file

Comment: Shouldn't you be reading a line from the file for _every_ row of the puzzle?  After reading the first line with the puzzle dimensions, you only read one more line, and then keep using it to fill in all the puzzle rows.

Comment: I have just tried your code and it works fine (as in no error)

Comment: @KevinAnderson yes, do I keep using that same code to read every line

Comment: Yes, the code you have for reading a puzzle line is fine, it just needs to go inside the loop on `rows`.  Also, the outer loop on `i` is entirely unnecessary; you only need two levels (rows and columns) of loop nesting, not a third.

Comment: @ScaryWombat it is not reading from the file of the puzzle and formatting accordingly

Comment: Maybe you are either not using this code or you are not using this text file.

Comment: @KevinAnderson wait what codes are you referring to exactly that should below the row loop

Comment: @ScaryWombat I am, I do not know why I can't read this                                                6   6
{d e v o l g}
(r e d p h k)
{q c h z j c}
{p o a a f o}
{v a m m n l}
{q t f o x b}

Comment: `String wordFile = file1.nextLine();` -> enter the fully pathed file

Comment: The lines `String letters = file1.nextLine()...` and `char [] condensed = ...`; they need to be the first thing inside the loop on `rows`.   And then inside the loop on `column`, you need to be looking at `condensed[column]` rather than `condensed[i]`. Does that make sense?

Comment: I moved them, but don't understand what they are supposed to be fixing?

Comment: I still need to be able to read the two integer (6 and 6) from the first line to format my puzzle.